# Did the DIG command change?

Tags: linux, debian

When using the DIG command with the ANY parameter, it is not showing the information that used to be shown.

```
root@server:~# dig google.com ANY

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> google.com ANY
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 60353
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      ANY

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 186.202.26.26#53(186.202.26.26)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov 22 10:31:48 -03 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 39
```

Have there been changes to the DIG command?

Comment: Your query failed; the problem is in the DNS server your are using.

Comment: Do not use `ANY`. It never meant "all" as people think it is and now it is fully considered obsolete/deprecated, see RFC 8482. No matter what you are trying to do/troubleshoot, `ANY` is not the solution. PS: you are using a quite old `dig` version.

Answer (score 3):

No, `dig` hasn't changed.

The best practice on how to respond to `ANY` queries has changed...

See: RFC 8482 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8482